# Test for significant difference in the standard deviations of two groups

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation

Say I have group A, which has a standard deviation of 3, and group B, which has a standard deviation of 5.

Is there a statistics test to look for whether the difference in standard deviations between the two groups is significant and not just a product of sampling?

In other words, if I want to say that the standard deviation of group A is 2 less than group B, what measures can I look at to see what confidence we can have in this statement?

Comment: The classic way is the F-test. I like this video on it: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7GJkxSYsX70. I can expand on the video in an answer or another comment if it doesn’t make sense. One note: population standard deviations are the same if and only if population variances are the same, so explicitly testing variance does answer your question.